# Drop Down menu on responsive layout

Tags: html, css

A.I am trying to create a responsive layout and it displays ok mostly but I am having troubles with the drop down menu on smaller screens. On smaller screen the add to cart div with z-index of 2000 is right below the navigation therefore my drop down menu hides under it when the mouse is hovered on any menu item. To avoid that I have added z-index:2000000 to my drop down menu bit it hasn't solved the problem. So I would really appreciate if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong?

B. I have seen jquery plugins like tinynav and responsive nav which convert the `<ul>` to `<select>` upon screen resize can the same thing work on drop down menus with nested `<ul>` elements as well?

Here is part of my css:

```
#cart {
width: 220px;
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 2000;
background: url(images/crt_bb.png);
overflow: hidden;
}
.sub-menu {
background-color: #fff;
border: #e6e6e6 1px solid;
border-radius: 3px;
position: absolute;
min-width: 170px;
z-index: 2000000;
display: none;
left: -20px !important;
}
```

Here is the url:http://daccordinc.com/
Resize the browser to smaller size and hover on shirts in navigation to see the issue.

Kind regards
Ahmar

Comment: You need to use media queries to either stack your menu or just make a mobile dropdown menu.  The way you have it set up right now is clunky.

Comment: hi @ChadP I am totally new and I am using media queries but I have no idea how to make it a mobile drop down I have seen some plugins but they are not for drop down menus

Comment: You can see the mobile menu I made for http://m.burtsbees.com

Comment: Just hide the normal menu under 800px and show the mobile menu. (vice versa for the opposite)

Comment: @AhmarAli Use some visiblity classes according to screen sizes and create a blocks for that.As a new one better try foundation.zurb.com or bootstrap.Which will you to make fast mobile responsive design.. :)